# Changing field layout in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal

I have a field called field_event_location, and this field has 5 different values possible for a location. These are set as check boxes (widget).

When the admin selects locations, these are all appended together (concatenated) without spaces or commas, making reading difficult.

The field type is term reference.

I'm trying to see if there's any additional way to stay this (it only needs minor styling).

Any suggestions? Do I need a custom module?

Comment: You could try to tackle this with CSS but a module is the standard way of handling it.  And this, THIS is why I will never work with Drupal again.  Simplest of tasks, hugest of headaches.  Lather...rinse...repeat...

Comment: I don't see an easy way to do this in CSS.

I figured I probably needed a module, ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from the *Pro Drupal Development* book:

```
$options = array(
    'poison' => t('Sprays deadly poison'),
    'metal'  => t('Can bite/claw through metal'),
    'deadly' => t('Killed previous owner')
);

$form['danger'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Special conditions'),
    '#type'  => 'checkboxes',
    '#description' => (t('Please note if any of these conditions apply to your pet')),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#weight' => 25
);
```

This should render a fieldset with the title, options *stacked vertically*, and the description below.

Comment: Where would I even put this?

Comment: In a custom module that alters the form when it's being built.